# how to find the filename for a matched string in PERL?

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I had some configured `$ReleaseLogPath` dir in my server and some string is there in `"lgtfileContent"` var. In `$ReleaseLogPath` dir there are many log files. I am trying to find the filename of a matched string (`lgtfileContent`) in `$ReleaseLogPath` path.i used the below line in my code, but it's not working.

```
my @files =  glob '$ReleaseLogPath/$lgtfileContent';
```

Any help please?

Comment: [*It's not working*](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) is a horrible way to describe your problem.

Comment: Are there spaces in the file names? If so, the default `glob` won't work correctly. Change it to the BSD glob: `use File::Glob qw( :bsd_glob );` See `perldoc File::Glob` http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html

Answer (score 3):

You should *never, ever* say "its not working" without specifying *how* its not working. It makes your problem much more difficult to understand. However, that line of code has a serious flaw: The single quoted string does not interpolate variables.

You might have better luck using double quotes:

```
my @files =  glob "$ReleaseLogPath/$lgtfileContent";
```

Of course, that all depends what string is in these variables, you may need to add wildcards to it, such as:

```
my @files =  glob "$ReleaseLogPath/$lgtfileContent*";
                                               #  ^--- here
```